The problem with the impulses in my physics engine
I have been analyzing the topic of creating a physics engine for a long time, at first I did it in a simple way, without thinking about real physics, then I began to do it on the basis of Verle integration. Relatively recently, I decided to make everything more realistic, switched to impulses, but ran into a problem. I calculate the value of the bounce pulse using the formula: double j = -(1 + k) * rxn; where:

k is the bounce coefficient, from 0 to 1
rvn is the Vec3.Dot(v2 - v1, normal).

This impulse is assigned to the first body in the form of the following vector: -normal * j * m1, and for the second body: normal * j * m2.
For the static-dynamic body combination, I just do the checks:
if(!first.rigid_body.active_data_settings.is_active) 
{ 
   m1 = m2 = second.mass; 
}  
else if(!second.rigid_body.active_data_settings.is_active) 
{ 
   m1 = m2 = first.mass; 
} 
else 
{ 
   m1 = first.mass; m2 = second.mass; 
}

Gravity and position I add at the beginning of the physical tick in the following way:
shape.position += step_delta * (shape.rigid_body.active_data.velocity + step_delta * gravity * 0.5d);
shape.rigid_body.active_data.AddVelocity(step_delta * gravity);

I did not add friction force and angular velocity. Everything works quite stably, but there are some cases when something strange happens, I have not been able to fix this problem for a long time.
The first case is if a dynamic sphere collides simultaneously between a static bounding box (floor) and a static sphere that is slightly higher than the dynamic sphere. (I have attached screenshots of the situations) In this case, the dynamic sphere seems to stop, but if you remove the static sphere, it suddenly starts sliding along the floor again in the direction in which it was sliding before the impact, although it was standing still before that.
The second case is if a dynamic sphere collides simultaneously between a static bounding box (floor) and a static sphere that is lower than the dynamic sphere, that is, it is half sunk into the floor. If the dynamic sphere was sliding at a very low speed, then after the collision, for some reason, it is thrown back with much greater force than before the impact. In all these cases, the Ostcock coefficient k was equal to 0.
For a better understanding, I will give the structure of one physics challenge. First, the position of the body is updated and gravity is added (I cited this above), then a list of pairs of bodies is created between which collisions must be checked and impulses calculated, all duplicates are deleted. After that, the intersections between them are checked and pairs of bodies are created, between which there is an intersection. Then the pulses are calculated, after which the positions of the bodies are adjusted to get rid of the drowning of one body in another, and after all this, all the lists that were created during the call (lists of pairs of bodies) are cleared.


